# How to add limit for the saved links in feedjira

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, feedjira

I  use ruby on rails, mongoid and feedjira to parse RSS links.

How to add a limit for the number of saved `feed_entries` at a time or a limit by the date of the link?
For example save only last 10 feed_enties.

My code:

```
def load_feed_entries
  feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(self.url)
  Source.add_entries(feed.entries, self.id)
end

private
  def self.add_entries(entries, stream_id)
    entries.each do |entry|
        unless  FeedEntry.where(guid: entry.id).exists?
          FeedEntry.create!(
            :link           => entry.url,
            :published_at  => entry.published,
            :guid          => entry.id,
          )
        end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Confused about the requirement here. Can you please give a scenario or example?

Comment: do you want to save only 10 latest(published date) articles into database from the fetched entries?

Comment: @AmitPatel yes.

Comment: First sort the `entries` by `published`  in descending and then take top 10 entries. Checkout `Array#sort_by` for sorting. Check `Accessing Elements` section in Ruby's `Array` doc.